# django request.POST data is empty but works with other similar form

Tags: python, html, django, forms, post

I'm new to django and I was following a tutorial from django on how to process POST form data with a model

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#using-a-form-in-a-view

I was able to do that for a simple login, and I can print out the variables in the console. The form.is_valid() function is true and works as expected for the login view.

I did the same exact thing for a registration page and I'm getting FALSE returned from the is_valid() function. I was tinkering with csrf tokens and that didn't seem to be causing the issue and thats why I didn't require them.

I think it's going to be a silly problem because I'm able to get the request.POST in the login case but not the registration. Any help is appreciated.

Here is my html form

```
 <div id="login" class="animate form">
                        <form  action="/signin" autocomplete="on" method ="POST"> 
                            <!--{% csrf_token} -->
                            <h1>Log in</h1> 
                            <p> 
                                <label for="username" class="uname" data-icon="u" > Your email or username </label>
                                <input id="username" name="username" required="required" type="text" placeholder="myusername or mymail@mail.com"/>
                            </p>
                            <p> 
                                <label for="password" class="youpasswd" data-icon="p"> Your password </label>
                                <input id="password" name="password" required="required" type="password" placeholder="eg. X8df!90EO" /> 
                            </p>
                            <p class="keeplogin"> 
              <input type="checkbox" name="loginkeeping" id="loginkeeping" value="loginkeeping" /> 
              <label for="loginkeeping">Keep me logged in</label>
            </p>
                            <p class="login button"> 
                                <input type="submit" value="Login" /> 

<div id="register" class="animate form">
                        <form  action="/register" autocomplete="on" method ="POST"> 
                            <!--{% csrf_token %} -->
                            <h1> Sign up </h1> 
                            <p> 
                                <label for="usernamesignup" class="uname" data-icon="u">Your username</label>
                                <input id="usernamesignup" name="usernamesignup" required="required" type="text" placeholder="mysuperusername690" />
                            </p>
                            <p> 
                                <label for="emailsignup" class="youmail" data-icon="e" > Your email</label>
                                <input id="emailsignup" name="emailsignup" required="required" type="email" placeholder="mysupermail@mail.com"/> 
                            </p>
                            <p> 
                                <label for="passwordsignup" class="youpasswd" data-icon="p">Your password </label>
                                <input id="passwordsignup" name="passwordsignup" required="required" type="password" placeholder="eg. X8df!90EO"/>
                            </p>
                            <p> 
                                <label for="passwordsignup_confirm" class="youpasswd" data-icon="p">Please confirm your password </label>
                                <input id="passwordsignup_confirm" name="passwordsignup_confirm" required="required" type="password" placeholder="eg. X8df!90EO"/>
                            </p>
                            <p class="signin button"> 
              <input type="submit" value="Sign up"/>
```

Here is the forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import CharField

class NameForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(label = 'username', max_length=25)
    password = forms.CharField(label = 'password', max_length=25)


class RegForm(forms.Form):
    regName = forms.CharField(label = 'usernamesignup', max_length = 25)
    regEmail = forms.CharField(label = 'emailsignup', max_length = 50)
    regPassword = forms.CharField(label = 'passwordsignup', max_length = 30)
    regPasswordConfirm = forms.CharField(label = 'passwordsignup_confirm', max_length = 30)
```

Here is the views.py that's handling login/registration (this is rough draft)

```
@csrf_exempt
def signin(request):
    #if this is a POST request we need to process the login credentials
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #create the form instance and populate with username/password
        form = NameForm(request.POST)
        #verify 
        print form
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            print username
            print password
            return render(request, 'webServer/home.html')
        else:
            return render(request, 'webServer/login.html')
    else:
        return render(request, 'webServer/login.html')

@csrf_exempt
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #create form instance and grab register credentials
        form2 = RegForm(request.POST)
        #verify not a duplicate entry (email, username)
        print form2
        if form2.is_valid():
            username = form2.cleaned_data['regPassword']
            return render(request, 'webServer/home.html')
        else:
            print 'had error'
            return render_to_response('webServer/errors.html',  {'form': form2})
    else:
        return render(request, 'webServer/login.html')
```

Comment: Which form has the issue? Why do you think POST is empty? If is_valid returns False, then what does `form.errors` contain? Why don't you show the errors on the template?

Comment: Sorry I thought I was clear in question. The registration form has the issue. The POST is empty because when I print out form2, I see no input. The errors in the template show that the fields are empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using completely different field names in the template from the form - your form has `regName`, `regEmail` etc, but your template has `usernamesignup` etc.

In any case, you should be using the form object itself to output the fields:

```
{{ form.regName.label_tag }}
{{ form.regName }}
{{ form.regName.errors }}
```

Comment: That's the issue. The field names and the template names didn't match. Changing the names from the regName.... to the corresponding template names fixed the issue. I didn't know they had to match